# Send Http Request via JScript

Tags: xmlhttprequest, jscript

I got a href from Website by inspect it, and I would like to send http request to update the value. But unfortunately the value isn't updated. And response text is the login page.

The href as below.

```
<a href="SystemTeam.do?formPostType=Update&ID=001&toggle=false">

My JScript as below.

 var baseURL = 
 "https://xx.xx.xx.xx/admin/SystemTeam.do?formPostType=Update&ID=001&toggle=true";
 var xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0");
 //Ignore SSL error.
 xmlHttpRequest.setOption(2,13056);
 xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", baseURL, false);
 //Set login user authorization
 xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic XXXXX");
 xmlHttpRequest.send();
```

Could anyone give some suggestions?

Comment: Looking at the URL, the data is there, so that it should be an HTTP GET request, rather than HTTP POST. Are you sure the method in the server is POST?

Comment: hello, even though I use GET, the name isn't updated, either.

Comment: Do you have access to the code on the server handling the request? Or it's really from a website you don't own?

Comment: It's really a website I don't own.